Rearranging fields in my MemberPress form also duplicates them
I want to modify my MemberPress registration form field order. I want email to be at the top rather than down below the username field where it sits by default.
I'm using this code in my child theme's functions.php file. It works, but it also duplicates the field on the form - now there are two email fields at the top - and I can't figure out how to fix it:
function mepr_reorder_fields() {
?>
<script>
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var email = $('.mepr_email');
        var firstname= $('.mepr_first_name');
        if(email.length) {
            email.insertBefore(firstname);  
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
 <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'mepr_reorder_fields' );

Here's my form with two email fields at the top:


The jQuery code takes a copy of whatever element(s) $('.mepr_email') catches and inserts it before the first name field. So possibly $('.mepr_email') returns more than one element? We can't tell. But if you inspect that jQuery object (e.g. by logging it to the console) you could see how many HTML elements it selected. You could also use the element inspector to check how many existing elements with the class mepr_email exist in your page when it first loads. That seems like the most likely explanation for this, but let's see what your debugging shows.

Either that or maybe mepr_reorder_fields() is executed twice, meaning the same jQuery code is added to the page twice, and thus runs twice.

I would highly recommend you use wp_footer instead here. That way, the form will be 99.9999% of the time, loaded before your jQuery is executed.

Switching from wp_head to wp_footer was the ticket! Thank you so much for that suggestion!!
